# What is the error in the link tag!! .. CSS is not getting linked.. am a beginner...

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Am trying to use "well", but i couldn't get it.i guess the probelm is in linking part, even i couldn't use any other features of CSS, am a beginner and couldn't get through this. Thanks in advance to anyone who helps in with this..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
           <title>Jothidhal</title>
           <meta charset = "utf-8">
           <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width ,  initial-scale = 1>
           <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "css/bootstrap.min.css>
       </head>
       <body>
           <div class = "container">
               <div class = "row">
                   <div class = "col-md-12 well" >col-12</div>//Am trying to use "well", but i couldn't get it.i guess the probelm is in linking part, even i couldn't use any other features of CSS, am a beginner and couldn't get through this. Thanks in advance to anyone who helps in with this.. 
               </div>
           </div>
           <script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
           <script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/jquery.js"></script>
       </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing closing `"`

```
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width ,  initial-scale = 1">
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If you are beginner and feeling linking problem of css and js file, just include the cdn files of bootstrap in your html file and write your code. I have included the cdn file in below code, look into this.           
<!DOCTYPE html>``
                <html>
                    <head>
                       <title>Jothidhal</title>
                       <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
                   </head>
                   <body>
                       <div class = "container">
                           <div class = "row">
                               <div class = "col-md-12 well" >col-12</div>//Am trying to use "well", but i couldn't get it.i guess the probelm is in linking part, even i couldn't use any other features of CSS, am a beginner and couldn't get through this. Thanks in advance to anyone who helps in with this.. 
                           </div>
                       </div>
                       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                   </body>
                </html>
```

Comment: Thank you sir!! :)\

Comment: @Durairaj  if it's really helped you, please accept the solution.

Comment: Sir actually the problem with my code was the missing " and i got done with that.  to be frank i haven't came across CDN before.   but am really thankful for introducing CDN to me... but STACK OVERFLOW allows me to accept only one solution.. am sorry that i couldn't accept yours.